# synchronized block doesn't lock the object

Tags: java, multithreading

Someone explain, why doesn't `synchronized block` lock the variable `_c` here?

```
public class static_thread  implements Runnable{
private static Integer _c=0;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
  for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
    if(i%2==0){_c++;}
  }
  System.out.println("one thread: "+_c);
  Thread[] t=new Thread[50];
  _c=0;
  for(int i=0;i<t.length;i++){
    t[i]=new Thread(new static_thread(i, i*(100000/50)));
    t[i].start();
  }
  for(Thread _:t){_.join();}
  System.out.println("+one thread: "+_c);//wrong answer!
}
  public void run() {
    for(int i=s;i<(s+l);i++){
      if(i%2==0){
        synchronized (_c) {//y u no lock?!
          _c++;//Inconsistence, not thread-safe, so what is synchronized block is doing here?
        }
      }
    }
  }
  int s,l;
  public static_thread(int s, int l) {
    this.s = s;
    this.l = l;
  }
}
```

for each run, I get new wrong value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By doing this

```
_c++
```

you are changing the reference that `_c` is holding. It is equivalent to

```
int value = _c.intValue();
_c = Integer.valueOf(value + 1);
```

Therefore

```
synchronized (_c) {
```

each time synchronizes on a different object.

Remember, **a `synchronized` block locks on an object, not a variable.**

You should always use `synchronized` with a variable that cannot change values, ie. make it `final`.

If you need a counter for some reason, consider using `AtomicInteger`.